Cannot access OpenShift cluster console due to IP issue
I am new to OpenShift and I have created an OpenShift cluster with 5 nodes all are VMs from vSphere via using Assited installer. The cluster was created successfully but I cannot access the cluster console.
This is my base domain and IPs, the IPs are empty ips from my VMs ips list

The error when I access the console

Can I ask is this the issue due to the IPs or the dns?
I can ping the IPs from another VM but cannot access the console on web browser.

can show us logs of openshift console pod? also make sure you access console in this format: https://:/api

I cannot access the console via https://:/api and I cannot check the logs via cli since I am using GUI to create the cluster.

Hello, I can access the https://:/ap via cli from another VM and I can see the pods and openshift are working. I have figured it out, there was no problem at all, I just need to login via cli from a VM and the url will work. Thanks for your guide.
